# Empty CommandArgument being passed. I've tried all other suggestions

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm at a loss. Can anyone tell me why a blank `CommandArgument` would be passed?

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="btnDrilldown" 
     runat="server" 
     CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LevelId") %>'  
                Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LevelId") %>' 
     OnCommand="btnDrilldown_OnCommand">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

This seems to be working. The `Text` field displays properly on the page. But what's passed is blank.

```
e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "".
```

So does

```
((LinkButton)sender).Text
```

and

```
string LevelId = ((LinkButton)sender).CommandArgument).
```

Any ideas?

```
protected void btnDrilldown_OnCommand(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
      string LevelId = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! Be sure to check what you're DataBinding on Page_Load. I was wiping out my params.